# Gadget can't be edited in blogger layout editor after using a downloaded template

Tags: blogger

I can't edit my blogger layout. On the section where I can add pages with links (menu), I can put specified posts in different pages.
Can I do it in the HTML template editor?
The template is free to use.

I tried the method of adding pages by adding gadgets, but no way.
I managed to add the pages on the HTML template editor, but it did not salve anything.

Answer (score 0):

On the section where you want to add gadgets maybe be fixed as 1 in template.
To unlock it,

1. Note the Section name
2. Go to themes-> Edit Html
3. Click on the html code and press ctrl+F and search the section Name
4. when you get the code there will be a line mentioned as `maxwidgets='1'`
5. Change the number as much as gadgets you want add.

Hope this will solve your issue,if you find any more issue or problem in solution comment below.